# Is a preposition necessary here: "It is irritating (to) me."?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions, sentence-meaning

> It is irritating me.
>
> It is irritating to me.

Which one is correct?
Does the word "irritating " work as an adjective in my second sentence?

Comment: Similar: *He always wants to please her. He is pleasing her. She finds it pleasing. It is pleasing to her. She is pleased.*

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are fine.

Without the preposition, the word 'me' is the direct object of the verb *irritate*.

With the preoposition, 'me' is the object of the preposition.

There is little difference between

> That music is irritating me

and

> That music is irritating to me.

(Compare: This test is challenging me. / This test is challenging to me.)

Except that the first one would normally be said only when you are currently being irritated by the music. The second sentence you can say whenever you like, even if that particular kind of music is not playing at the time.

Frankly, though, the active construction sounds much better:

> That music irritates me.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

However, in the first, *irritating* serves as a verb in present progressive tense.  It is irritating him **now**.

In the second example, *irritating* serves as a predicate adjective, describing "it". So "it" might *be irritating* whenever it happens!